# Space between two output labels in jsf

Tags: jsf

I am developing a page using JSF2.0 & prime faces i have a requirement that i need to place two output lables in as single line with space.

Like this

address 1: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                   address 2:

i wrote below code

```
            <h:panelGrid columns="2"  styleClass="companyHeaderGrid" >

                  <p:outputLabel value="Address 1 : " />
            <h:outputText value="38th Street Pharmacy" /> 

            <!-- Here i need Address 2 at the right side of the page same line to the address 1-->


            <p:outputLabel value="State  : " />
            <h:outputText value="Texas" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Zip Code : " />
            <h:outputText value="123456" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Phone : " />
            <h:outputText value="9700300009" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Fax: " />
            <h:outputText value="" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Contact Person : " />
            <h:outputText value="Clinton Albrecht" />

         </h:panelGrid>
```

i tried with many ways like both  address 1 and aaddress 2 palces in a pannel grid  with 4 columns and  i tried to get  space using "spacer" tags, but it gives the outpit in different way..

please help me

Thanks before Nani

Comment: You can replace `<h:outputText value="38th Street Pharmacy" />` with `<h:panelGroup>  <h:outputText value="#{bean.address1}" />  <h:outputLabel value="Address 2 : " />  <h:outputText value=" #{bean.address2}" />  </h:panelGroup>` and setup style for group `style="width: 100%"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't achieve `colspan` or `rowspan` in plain JSF, you will need to do it with a plain HTML table or with [PrimeFaces PanelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml).